# How to Click "Yes" button in order application with code

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user32

I have a code

```
 private const int WM_CLOSE = 16;
    private const int BN_CLICKED = 245;
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);



 public void Click(string _btnTitle)
    {
        int hwnd = 0;
        IntPtr hwndChild = IntPtr.Zero;

        //Get a handle for the Calculator Application main window
        // foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
        //{   
        hwnd = FindWindow(null, FrmTitle);            
        if (hwnd != 0)
        {
            hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", _btnTitle);
            SendMessage((int)hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

I can't Click button "Yes" on MessageBox of application :(

Anyone got a tip? Tks

Comment: Just to be sure, "hwnd" and "hwndChild" do have values ?

Comment: Did you check to make sure hwndChild returned a valid button?  I used this technique extensively in a past life (config mgmt of 3k+ workstation) and usually the biggest job was "climbing the tree" of windows to make sure you had the right control before sending the "click" message to it.  I would usually use an app to manually find the window I wanted and THEN write the code to search for, find and send the message I wanted.  (If your actual code is more complex than example you may need to get "parent" window in correct state before it would actually "listen" to the "click" message.

Comment: Have you used spy++ or other tool to make sure your hwndChild is the window you think it should be? Also, is FrmTitle actually the form? Shouldn't you be passing in its handle?

Comment: This code work in main form of application but in Messagebox :( it not work

Comment: Have you tried looking for the string literal `&Yes` instead of `Yes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending the correct message.

Try using `BM_CLICK` (0x00F5) in your call to SendMessage(). That should work provided that `hwndChild` is the window handle of the button, rather than the container dialog box.

`BN_CLICKED` doesn't work because that is a *notification* code, not a message.

Comment: Good answer, and precisely correct! I've removed the line from your answer expressing concern about the age of the question, because that's not something we consider to be important on Stack Overflow. No matter how old the question is, if you have a good answer, you should share it, just like you did! We always get new traffic from Google, and there are plenty of people your answer could still help.